# C# application keep running after closing windows XP

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp

when I close the application from task management. I have discovered that he keeps running in windows xp for a few minutes. I have already Search the forum but found nothing that comes close to it.

I use .net 2.0 because it is often already older systems.

I hope you are able to help me.

I use also a Form_closing void :

```js
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {

  if (e.CloseReason == System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing || e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) {
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
  } else {
    DialogResult result = new DialogResult();
    result = MessageBox.Show("Weet je zeker dat je de interface wil sluiten? Hiermee word de automatische werkening gestopt!!", "Afsluiten", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    if (result == DialogResult.No) {
      e.Cancel = true;

    } else
      e.Cancel = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: The process not immediately shutting down is an indication for your process still having an active thread that is either waiting/blocking on some system resource (pehaps something network-related, perhaps something else) until it times out, or a so-called "foreground thread" still running (a foreground thread is a thread that is not a background thread; and a process only terminates when _all_ foreground threads end/complete execution). Use the debugger to analyze the state of the program and its threads when you attempt to close it...

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();

Answer (score 0):

i found my problem in a connection that was kept open